# Creating Generic React Function Component With Type That Ensures Presence of a Property

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I have been trying to create a react component that abstracts out a material-ui component. I have several model interfaces that should be assignable to a prop of the component. I want the other props to infer their types based on that specific prop.

For example here are my interfaces:

```typescript
interface Job {
  id: number;
  roleName: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  jobs: Job[];
}
```

The component that I want to make uses material-ui styling. It can take a prop that is a list of any of the above models. It also takes a callback to specify how to obtain a displayable string for that model. Here is what I've come up with that doesn't work:

```typescript
const componentStyles = (theme: Theme) =>
  createStyles({
    text: {
      color: "#000000",
})

interface ObjectWithId<T> {
  id: number;
}


interface ComponentProps<T extends ObjectWithId> extends WithStyles<typeof componentStyles> {
  objects: T[]; // <--- infer based on this?
  getListString: <K extends keyof T>(obj: T) => T[K];
}
```

And then the component declaration is:

```
function MyComponent<T extends ObjectWithId>(props: ComponentProps<T>) {

  return <ul>
     {props.objects.map((obj) => 
      <
        li key={obj.id} // <-- we expect this
           className={props.classes.text}
      >
        {props.getListString(obj)}
      </li>
  </ul>
}
```

And finally its expected usage:

```typescript
// some other component function body
const job = {id: 1, roleName: "programmer"} as Job;

return <MyComponent objects=[job] getListString={(job) => job.roleName} />
```

**The error I receive is that roleName does not exist on the `ObjectWithId`**, which I understand, but, I'm trying to make this generic and currently have run out ideas. I have looked at several articles and docs including:

- https://mariusschulz.com/blog/passing-generics-to-jsx-elements-in-typescript
- https://wanago.io/2020/03/09/functional-react-components-with-generic-props-in-typescript/

I don't want to have to do something like:

```typescript
  type AllModelTypes = Job | User;
  ComponentProps<T extends AllModelTypes> {...};
```

So, how do I do this the correct way? Or is this not possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the trick:

```
import * as React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";

interface Job {
  id: number;
  roleName: string;
}

interface User {
  id: number;
  name: string;
  jobs: Job[];
}

interface ObjectWithId {
  id: number;
}

interface ComponentProps<T extends ObjectWithId, K extends keyof T> {
  objects: T[]; // <--- infer based on this?
  getListString: (obj: T) => T[K];
}

function MyComponent<T extends ObjectWithId, K extends keyof T>(props: ComponentProps<T, K>) {
  return (<ul>
     {props.objects.map((obj) => 
      <li key={obj.id}>
        {props.getListString(obj)}
      </li>
     )}
  </ul>);
}

class App extends React.Component<{}, {}> {
  public render() {
    const job = {id: 1, roleName: "programmer"} as Job; // Not needed but makes intelisense cleaner
    const user = {id :2, name: 'Milton', jobs: [job]} as User;
    return (
      [<MyComponent objects={[job]} getListString={(job) => job.roleName} />,
      <MyComponent objects={[user]} getListString={(user) => user.name} />]
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Disclaimer: I am not 100% certain why my changes work so if someone can answer with more certainty why this works please do! I used my intuition around TypeScript to find this solution that works based on my experience.

What I've changed:
First I've removed the generic part of ObjectWithId, not sure why that was added but there were two issues, first that the generic part wasn't used inside of the type or wasn't used to constrain the type but it also wasn't being used by the component types to pass on more type info.

Secondly I've moved the creation of the second generic K into the generics arguments of ComponentProps. I think this is needed/works because this way the T and K types are created in the same place and are thus more linked so you end up with the right inference happening but I can't answer for why this is this way so again, if anyone knows WHY this works this way do add that to an answer or edit this one.

Comment: thanks! I made ObjectWithId generic due to exasperation. I believe your solution works. However, I needed to refactor my code since I couldn't do, `withStyles(componentStyles)(MyComponent)`. The error was that the generic component was unassignable to the first arg of withStyles. I ended up using the hook api instead.

Answer (score -1):

https://reactjs.org/docs/typechecking-with-proptypes.html

What you want can use prop types library. You can make some property of a component required or optional

Comment: Prop types is a runtime check, the OP is asking how to do this with TypeScript so he gets compile time support